# How to solve this ListView unexpected cast issue?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I want to display a `listView` on my main activity but im getting an error that says : unexpected cast to `ListViewCompat` : lay out tag was `ListView`.

Here is the `java` code -

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {


    //variable del toolbar o app_bar
    private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;

    //variable del list view
    ListViewCompat l;

    //arreglo que va a contener los datos de el listView
    String [] parqueaderos = {"Las vegas","Los guayabos","Regional 1", "Regional 2"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //se le da el valor de el app_bar o toolbar que creamos a la variable toolbar que creamos en esta clase
        toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);


        //se aclara que no se va a usar el toolbar de android si no el mio (app_bar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        //se le da el valor a a la variable del listView la "apariencia" del xmls del listView
        **l = (ListViewCompat) findViewById(R.id.lista);**
        //Se crea el array adapter que va a tomar los datos del array de Strings parqueaderos y los va a mostrar en el listView
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,parqueaderos);
        //se le pasa el adapter con el arreglo a la listView l
        l.setAdapter(adapter);



    }
```

And here is the layout code -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- incluimos el layout del app bar -->
    <include

        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar">

    </include>

    <!-- Aquí va la imagen que se ve en la clase principal con el logo de la universdad -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/eafit4"
        android:id="@+id/imgppal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



    <!-- ésta es la lista que contiene los parqueaderos -->

    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgppal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="389dp"
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_weight="0.79" />







</RelativeLayout>
```

Do any one know how to solve this problem?

Thanks very much for reading.

Comment: post your logcat error here.

Comment: Please post your logcat output

Comment: What is `findViewById`?

Comment: it is not a logcat error, it just says that in the line l = (ListViewCompat) findViewById(R.id.lista);

Comment: that line is the one that displays the error

Comment: l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista); use this

Comment: As per me try to replace this line (ListViewCompat) findViewById(R.id.lista);
with (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

Comment: @JimGarrison i used findViewById to give the value of the listView (called lista) to the variable l.

Comment: Whatever is being returned by `findViewById` is not compatible with the type `ListViewCompat`.  Until you show us the definition of `findViewById` it will be hard for anyone to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys, i changed the type of the expression to the library that contains Listview and used ListView instead, everything works just fine now, thanks a million !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to use `ListViewCompat`? If it's not what you intended to do, replace all `ListViewCompat` with `ListView`, since `ListViewCompat` is subclass of `ListView` and you cannot cast base class to subclass. Otherwise, use `ListViewCompat` in layout file instead of `ListView`.